# Get subscriber and publisher from ros2 topic info

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run `ros2 topic info <topic_name>`, it only gives me the type, publisher count and subscriber count, but not the publishing node and subscribing nodes.  How can I also get that information, similar ot how `rostopic info <topic_name>` works?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353820/get-subscriber-and-publisher-from-ros2-topic-info/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get it with the `-v` flag: `ros2 topic info -v <topic_name>`.

---

Originally posted by [khaiyichin](https://answers.ros.org/users/43473/khaiyichin/) with karma: 76 on 2021-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5